# Why this SQL query returning exact duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query written, which is giving me exact duplicate records.

Can't figure out why. Need your help, please.

I need to know what is causing the query to show duplicate records.

Here is the query, followed by the schema.

Query:

```
select 
    p.Scode Property,
    IsNull(u.Scode, '') Unit,
    IsNull(ISNULL(t.sCode, tr.SD2), '') Payer,
    'R-' + RTrim(LTrim(Convert(Varchar(9), tr.Id-600000000))) Receipt,
    tr.uPDate 'Post Date',
    tr.sDateOccurred 'Date Occurred',
    tr.sTotalAmount 'Total Amount',
    Case tr.sAmountPaid 
       When Null Then '' When 0 Then 0 Else '' 
    End 'Amount Paid'
from 
    P p
INNER JOIN 
    TR tr ON tr.hprop = p.Id
INNER JOIN 
    GT dt ON isnull(tr.HP5,0) = Case when 'Non-P' = 'Non-P' Then 2 else dt.Id end
LEFT JOIN 
    T t on isnull(tr.HPERSON,0) = Case when 'Ten' = 'Non-Ten' Then 0 else t.Id end
LEFT JOIN 
    U u ON u.Id = tr.hUnit
WHERE
    1 = 1
    and p.Id = 99
    and tr.uPDate Between convert(datetime, '01-Apr-2015', 106) And convert(datetime, '01-Apr-2015', 106)
ORDER BY
    p.sCode, u.sCode, t.sCode, tr.SD2, tr.uPDate
```

Schema:

**P**

```
Id int Primary key
Scode varchar(20)
...
```

**T**

```
Id int Primary Key
Scode varchar(20)
...
```

**U**

```
Id int Primary key
Scode varchar(20)
...
```

**TR**

```
Id bigint Primary Key
hP int FK(P)
hP5 int
hPerson FK(T)
SD2 varchar(20)
hUnit int FK(U)
uPDate Date
...
```

**GT**

```
Id int Primary Key
Scode varchar(20)
...
```

**Sample Query Output**

```
lwheight                Laundry     R-1016071   2015-04-01  2015-04-17  350.00  0
lwheight                Laundry     R-1016071   2015-04-01  2015-04-17  350.00  0
lwheight    1104        t0026989    R-1009490   2015-04-01  2015-04-06  832.28  0
lwheight    1104        t0026989    R-1009490   2015-04-01  2015-04-06  832.28  0
```

Comment: Do any of the component tables have duplicate entries?  Are you certain the records are really the same (i.e. no whitespace issues)?

Comment: question is well formed but may be case conditions doing the damage because you are joining table with case condition when case 'Non-P' = 'Non-P' Then 2 means if it have 2 records it will give multiple records

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - There are no any duplicate records and neither there is any white space issue. That's the thing! :|

Comment: The only advice I can give you is to tease apart the query into smaller pieces, and then try to see where your joining logic might be introducing duplicates.

Comment: As @Jonathan pointed out, you have constants in you `CASE WHEN` conditions which means you will always get the same result, so the first CASE becomes `INNER JOIN GT dt ON tr.HP5 = 2` which is likely to give you _unwanted results_.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the data in the tables. You are joining P with TR. TR may contain more than 1 row with the same value in TR.hprop and then you will get duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Jonathan was right.
The case statement was causing an issue.
I changed the query to this:

```
select p.Scode Property,
IsNull(u.Scode, '') Unit,
IsNull(ISNULL(t.sCode, tr.SD2), '') Payer,
'R-' + RTrim(LTrim(Convert(Varchar(9), tr.Id-600000000))) Receipt,
tr.uPDate 'Post Date',
tr.sDateOccurred 'Date Occurred',
tr.sTotalAmount 'Total Amount',
Case tr.sAmountPaid When Null Then '' When 0 Then 0 Else '' End 'Amount Paid'
from P p
INNER JOIN TR tr ON tr.hprop = p.Id
INNER JOIN GT dt ON isnull(tr.HP5,0) = gt.Id and gt.scode = 'z-nonper'
LEFT JOIN T t on isnull(tr.HPERSON,0) = t.Id
LEFT JOIN U u
ON u.Id=tr.hUnit
WHERE
1 = 1
and p.Id=99
and tr.uPDate Between convert(datetime, '01-Apr-2015', 106) And convert(datetime, '01-Apr-2015', 106)
ORDER BY
p.sCode,
u.sCode,
t.sCode,
tr.SD2,
tr.uPDate
```

And It worked as required.
Thanks. :)